# Hide all divs by default on pageload, display:none doesn't appear to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visibility, show-hide

For some reason, i can't get this div to be hidden by default. I want the page to be loaded and no divs to be visible until the user clicks one of the 3 links however by default the first div 'newboxes1' is always visible.

the div id id 'newboxes' and the class is telling 'newboxes' to 'display:none' so I can't see why it wouldn't work.

HTML

```
<div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 5px; width: 100px;">
        <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');" ><strong>1</strong>    </a>
     </div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="background-color: #ffffff; display: block;padding: 5px; width: 426px; margin-left:6px; background-color:#f4f2f2;">
     <img src="" width="241" height="36">
  <p class="intro">title</p><br>
  <p>text here<br><br>
  <a href=""><img src="" alt="" width="200" height="31" style="float:left;"> </a>
  <a href=""><img class="reg_box" src="" alt="" width="200" height="31"></a><br>
</div>

     <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 5px; width: 240px;">
        <a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');" ><strong>2</strong>   </a>
     </div>
     <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="background-color: #ffffff; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 426px; margin-left:6px;">
     <img src="" width="241" height="36">
  <p class="intro">title 2</p><br>
  <p>text here<br><br>
  <a href=""><img src="" alt="" width="200" height="31" style="float:left;"> </a>
  <a href=""><img class="reg_box" src="" alt="" width="200" height="31"></a><br>
</div>

     <div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 5px; width: 100px;">
        <a id="myHeader4" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes4');" ><strong>3</strong>  </a>
     </div>
     <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes4" style="background-color: #ffffff; display: none;padding: 5px; width: 426px; margin-left:6px;">
     <img src="" width="350" height="36">
  <p class="intro">test 3</p><br>
  <p>text here<br><br>
  <a href=""><img src="" alt="" width="200" height="31" style="float:left;"> </a>
  <a href=""><img class="reg_box" src="" alt="cis register" width="200" height="31"></a>   <br>
  </div>
```

JS

```
<script>
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show(200);
      }
        else {
           $(this).hide(600);
      }
 });
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
#newboxes {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Any URI where we could test and even see what's wrong ?

Comment: Sure yes, sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/FFMRe/

Comment: Although this doesn't seem to work within jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newboxes` is a class and in the css must me declared as a `class` not as an `id`.

You should start by changing this:

```
#newboxes {
    display:none;
}
```

into this:

```
.newboxes {
    display:none;
}
```

You need also to remove `display: block;` from inline style of `newboxes1`.

Comment: I had changed #newboxes to .newboxes previously as I wasn't too sure which one was correct in this situation with no results however removing display"block from the first element fixed the issue so working now (I didn't even spot that) thanks

Answer (score 0):

check your css style you are using `#newboxes { display:none; }`

## goes for id, you should use .newboxes { display:none; } since . will get all the classes.